# Excel add maths keyboard shortcuts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, autocorrect

How can I get excel 2013 to auto correct maths? For example change \int into ∫. I know how to do it for one symbol but is there any way to get excel to recognise all the maths auto corrects?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to type english and have it convert that to the math symbols and/or functions?

Comment: @Raystafarian  so on Microsoft word you have the option the option to use maths auto correct outside equations (found in options->proofing ->AutoCorrect options->Maths Autocorrect -> Use Math AutoCorrect rules outside of math regions.) So I was wondering if there was something equivalent in excel.

Comment: I've never seen it, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist standard or as an add-in. Someone will come along to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft (in their infinite wisdom) does not have the `Application.OMathAutoCorrect.UseOutsideOMath = True` option available within either the Excel Options ► Proofing ► AutoCorrect Options ► Math AutoCorrect or directly through Excel's VBA. IMHO, this is likely due to Excel's limitations on displaying the true Unicode characters and some regular ASCII characters like the *tick* (aka *single quote* or ASCII 039) that are used for other purposes. If something cannot be done completely and work through several optional language packs, then the whole process was likely shelved until a resolution was arrived at. When Excel is within its math editor, a different interface is being exchanged with and all symbols can be properly displayed.

I've prepared a full list of the Math AutoCorrect symbols on my OneDrive [here](http://1drv.ms/1vzWVmZ) for you to look at: [Excel_2013_OMathAutoCorrectEntries.xlsx](http://1drv.ms/1vzWVmZ). There are some very notable omissions like `\grave` and `\bar` that Excel either autocorrects or interprets for other purposes but the majority of symbols are just fine.

This just means that we have to work around the limitation and accept any shortcomings. While Excel's VBA use of the `OMathAutoCorrect` object is somewhat crippled, the one in Word is not. If we take all of the entries from the `OMathAutoCorrectEntries` collection and convert them as additions to the standard `AutoCorrectEntries` collection, then they will be available within all Office programs including Excel. The end results in each of the Office programs may vary.

Close Excel and all other Office programs then open Word to a new blank document and tap `Alt+F11` to enter the VBE. Use the pull-down menus to Insert ► Module (or `Alt+I, M`). Paste the following into the new pane titled something like *Normal - NewMacros (Code)* or *Normal - Module1 (Code)*.

```
Sub Normalize_Math_AutoCorrect_Entries()
    Dim acm As Long, ac As Long, yn As Long, cACEs As AutoCorrectEntries
    Set cACEs = Application.AutoCorrect.Entries
    With Application.OMathAutoCorrect
        .UseOutsideOMath = False    'no longer necessary
        For acm = 1 To .Entries.Count
            yn = vbYes
            For ac = 1 To cACEs.Count
                If cACEs(ac).Name = .Entries(acm).Name Then
                     yn = MsgBox(cACEs(ac).Name & " is currently assigned to " & cACEs(ac).Value & _
                       Chr(46) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Are you sure you want to replace it?", _
                       vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Duplication")
                    If yn = vbYes Then cACEs(ac).Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next ac
            If yn = vbYes Then _
                Application.AutoCorrect.Entries.Add Name:=.Entries(acm).Name, Value:=.Entries(acm).Value
        Next acm
    End With
    Set cACEs = Nothing
End Sub
```

With that in place, tap `Alt+Q` to return to your blank document. Tap `Alt+F8` to open the Macros dialog and run the macro. If a duplicate entry is encountered, the process will be paused and you will be presented with something like the following.

[image: AutoCorrect overwrite confirmation]

Note that I have chosen one that can actually be displayed. Many of the Unicode characters will only be represented by an `?` since a standard VBA message box cannot display Unicode. This does not mean that the symbol will be added incorrectly. Like Excel this is a display limitation.

Accept or reject the overwrites. Anything not already found within the standard `AutoCorrectEntries` collection will be added without asking.

When this process is complete, all of the `OMathAutoCorrect` entries will have been *normalized* as standard `AutoCorrect` entries. If you open Excel, they should be available immediately. Here is a before and after typing the space that forces the autocorrection after *\beta*.

[image: \beta before space]

[image: \beta after space]

On a related note, I wrote an article a while back you may be interested in on the use of stylized fractions within Office programs through additions to the standard `AutoCorrect` collection. Here is a link to that:

[Styled Fractions in Windows](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-word/styled-fractions-in-windows/4a07d5fa-2484-4e39-b1f3-70bb3eb0c332)

Now I have to get to work on writing a reversal routine so that the entries can be removed. Since there is some duplication between the two collections, I'm not sure how to handle confirmation as there are a total of 496 entries in a default `OMathAutoCorrect` collection.

Comment: HI, did you ever finish a " revert the `AutoCorrectEntries` to the  previous state"  macro?   Alternatively,  do you know whether the original set of autocorrect items is stored in a file, so that one  could save a copy prior to running the macro to load the Math set?

Comment: Found them:  `usr/appdata/roaming/microsoft/office/*.acl`